# Simple Login using DataBinding in MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

```
 buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
```

databinding enabled in gradle

below is my XML in which databinding is enabled and viewmodel as variable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.ohc.ohcadmin.allViewModel.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/m_20"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/h1"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/m_150"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/m_150"
                android:src="@mipmap/logo_3"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/f_20"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/msg_username"
                style="@style/tiEitText"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/f_20"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivLogo">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="@={vm.loginUser.username}"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/tiEitText"
                android:hint="@string/msg_password"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilUserName">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:text="@={vm.loginUser.password}"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/m_20"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
                android:onClick="@{()-> vm.Login()}"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/m_20"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilPassword" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

login activity using hilt getting viewmodel

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
    class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
        private val viewmodel:LoginViewModel by viewModels()
        @Inject lateinit var helper: Helper
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)
    
            initViews()
        }
    
        private fun initViews() {
            binding.vm = viewmodel
            binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    
        }
    }
```

ViewModel a simple method to validate username and password, if both are validated return valid

```
 @HiltViewModel
    class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel(){
    
          val loginUser = MutableLiveData<LoginUser>(LoginUser(username = "", password = ""))
    
        val PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$".toRegex()
    
        fun Login():String{
            Log.d("TAG", "reached")
            var s = "valid"
            if(loginUser.value?.username.isNullOrEmpty()){
                s = "please enter username"
            }
            else if(loginUser.value?.password.isNullOrEmpty()){
                s = "Please enter password"
            }
            else if(!PATTERN.matches(loginUser.value?.password!!)){
                s = "At least 8 character with 1 digital, upper,lower &amp; special char "
            }
           return s
        }
    
    
    }
```

I am unable to valiadte and login using databinding from xml on button click unable to access Login() method in viewmodel if Login method is refered from loginActivity unable to validate username and password properly.

Comment: Watch Fragment or activity With LiveData, you can send a value and observe it and pass it on.

Comment: `fun Login()` return `String` it does nothing for `android:onClick=""`

Comment: changed login method as below .............  fun Login(){
        if(loginUser.value?.username.isNullOrEmpty()){
           Log.d(s, "please enter username")
        }
        else if(loginUser.value?.password.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Log.d(s, "Please enter password")
        }
        else if(!PATTERN.matches(loginUser.value?.password!!)){
            Log.d(s, "At least 8 character with 1 digital, upper,lower &amp; special char ")
        }
        else{
            Log.d(s, "valid login logic")
        }

    }

Comment: but when even after username is entered ini login screen , I am getting log as please enter username

Comment: `MutableLiveData<LoginUser>()` is null value. Init it with data class `MutableLiveData(LoginUser(...))`

Comment: Tq thats working for me...